# Lead Assignment Rules run TWICE

Tags: assignment-rules

I seem to be experiencing a unique situation as searching for other examples come up with few, if any, results.

I have a function that works as follows: There is a button on the Contact record called "Create Internal Lead" which does just that.

1. Click the button, a visualforce page comes up with options for which CAMPAIGN to have the lead created be a member of
2. Select the campaign and click 'Create'
3. The lead is created and becomes a member of the campaign.

Simple.  However in the Apex Controller, the lead assignment rules are also triggered.

When a lead is created, is runs through the lead assignment rules, then has some regular workflow and other triggers appending data... then is is pushed through the lead assignment rules AGAIN.

The lead assignment rules are **NOT TRIGGERED in ANY code**, nor in any workflow, process flow, anything.  ***There is NOTHING that is saying at any point anywhere, 'run lead assignment rules'.***

The logs show the lead being created, running through the assignment rules, and then workflows rules and code firing to do their respective things.
THEN, the log has (for no reason or trigger) the lead assignment rules firing again.

[image: assignment fires twice]

Since the code finishes, what is causing assignment rules to run again?
[image: assignment 2 firing again]

HERE IS the Controller to create the lead - trimmed down from error messages and other un-important things.

```
public class CreateInternalLeadController 
{


public PageReference save()
{

    try {
        if(String.isBlank(businessUnit))
        {
            SfdcUtil.addErrorMessageToPage(ERR_BUSINESS_UNIT_REQUIRED);
            return null;
        }

        CreateInternalLeadBusinessUnit__c bizUnitSetting = CreateInternalLeadBusinessUnit__c.getAll().get(businessUnit);

                //find the campaign
                List<Campaign> campaigns = [select Id, Name from Campaign where Name = :bizUnitSetting.Lead_Assignment_Queue_Name__c and IsActive = true];

                campName = campaigns.get(0).Name;
                Id campaignId = campaigns.get(0).Id;

                //Jun/2017 - change to find matching lead by email
                String email = isContact ? theContact.Email : theCase.Contact.Email;
                Lead[] leadMatches = [select Id, Email, Status from Lead where Email = :email and IsConverted = false];

                //create Lead
                Lead leadObj = new Lead(Lead_Description__c = comments);

                //populate lead with Case or Contact info
                if(isContact) 
                {
                    populateLead(leadObj, theContact, (leadMatches.isEmpty() ? null : leadMatches.get(0)));
                }


                Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
                if(leadObj.Id == null) {
            //NEW
            dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = true;
            Database.insert(leadObj, dmo);

            //create CampaignMember
            CampaignMember campMember = new CampaignMember(
                LeadId = leadObj.Id, 
                CampaignId = campaignId, 
                Internal_Lead_Share__c = TRUE,
                DHR_Sales_Rep_Name__c = u.Name,
                DHR_Sales_Rep_Email__c = u.Email);
            insert campMember;

        }


        private void populateLead(Lead leadObj, Contact c, Lead matchingExistingLead) 
        { 

    leadObj.Lead_Type__c = 'Existing Contact';
    leadObj.Company = c.Account.Name;
    leadObj.FirstName = c.FirstName;
    leadObj.Camp__c = campName;
    leadObj.LastName = c.LastName;        
    leadObj.Email = c.Email;
    leadObj.Street = c.MailingStreet;
    leadObj.PostalCode = c.MailingPostalCode;
    leadObj.City = c.MailingCity;
    leadObj.Country = c.MailingCountry;
    leadObj.State = c.MailingState;
    leadObj.Phone = c.Phone;
    leadObj.MobilePhone = c.MobilePhone;
    leadObj.Internal_Lead_Share__c = TRUE;
    leadObj.Status = 'Open';
    leadObj.Marketing_Lead_Score__c = 'A1';
    leadObj.Lead_Assignment_Date__c = Date.today();
    leadObj.Market_Segment__c = c.Market_Segment_St__c;
    leadObj.Title = c.Title;
    leadObj.Department__c = c.Department;
    leadObj.Job_Function__c = c.Job_Functions_07__c;
    leadObj.Business_Segment__c = c.Business_Segment_Most_Recent__c;
    leadObj.DHR_Sales_Rep_Name__c = UserInfo.getName();
    leadObj.DHR_Sales_Rep_Email__c  = UserInfo.getUserEmail();        
    CreateInternalLeadBusinessUnit__c bizUnitSetting = CreateInternalLeadBusinessUnit__c.getAll().get(businessUnit);

    if(bizUnitSetting != null && !String.isBlank(bizUnitSetting.Intent_Field__c)) {
        leadObj.put(bizUnitSetting.Intent_Field__c, 'C - Cool (>12 months purchase)');
    }else{
        leadObj.Intent_To_Purchase__c = 'C - Cool (>12 months purchase)';
    }
}
}
```

Comment: can you post your code to create lead?

Comment: code added - but this is from a controller... so it is only called once

Comment: was this resolved?